# Put the selectbox in php html

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to put the select clause in php html.

here my code:

```
<?php 
for($index=1; $index<=$content->option->dynamic_field_index; $index++){
 echo "<td><select name='kboard_option_product' 
 id='kboard_option_product{$index}' data-placeholder='selectProduct'>";
 echo "<optgroup value='0' label='products'>";
 echo "<option value='windows'>windows</option>";
 echo "<option value='linux'>linux</option>";                
 echo "<option value='unix'>unix</option>";
 echo "</optgroup></select></td>";
 }?>
```

How can I fix it?
I want to do that in

If you look at the options below you will save the data like this, but if you use echo, you have to match php syntax and html syntax.

```
 <option value="window"<?php if($content->option->product == 'window'):?> selected<?php endif?>>window</option>
```

What I want to do is to use the for statement in the php clause and use the tag with echo to show it as html

Comment: Your Question is not clear; Please edit your question as more readable

Comment: please provide more details about your question

Comment: You should move the select tag outside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the following ,

```
function php_selectbox(){
   ob_start();
   ?>
      //Place your html here and echo the function outside.
   <?php
   return ob_get_clean();

}
```